# After Ubuntu installation There was no sound output at all & my build-in speakers aren't recognized on 22.04

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, system

i have tired the following steps :
Step 1 – Update System Packages
Step 2 – Install Pulse and Alsa Audio Drivers
Step 3 – Reload the Alsa Driver

but on step 2 , it took too long and the code didn't really execute